# cannot update oracle sql table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

have this code:

```
select clientinfo.client_surname, mi.medicine_price from clientinfo 
    join orderinfo oi on oi.client_id = clientinfo.client_id
    join ordered_medicines om on om.order_id = oi.order_id
    join medicine_instances mi on om.medicine_id_instance = mi.medicine_id_instance
    where add_months(birthdate, 65*12) < CURRENT_DATE and mi.medicine_price in (select max(medicine_price) from medicine_instances);
update
(select mi.medicine_price
from clientinfo 
    join orderinfo oi on oi.client_id = clientinfo.client_id
    join ordered_medicines om on om.order_id = oi.order_id
    join medicine_instances mi on om.medicine_id_instance = mi.medicine_id_instance
    where add_months(birthdate, 65*12) < CURRENT_DATE and mi.medicine_price in (select max(medicine_price) from medicine_instances)
    ) T
    set T.medicine_price = T.medicine_price * 0.98;
```

but whe i try to run it i got an error:
ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table

i googled, but didnt understand how to fix it. What`s the problem?

Comment: I assume your several joins are the "right kind" - you have successive lookups, and in each case you are joining to a lookup table in which the join column is the primary key. Alas, unless you explicitly told Oracle, via constraints or indexes, that certain columns are "primary key" or "unique", Oracle won't know that and it will assume that there will at least *potentially* be ambiguities. If my assumption is correct, the **right** way to fix this is to declare the primary key (or unique key) constraints explicitly. Then the `update` should work as written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use corelation as follows:

```
Update medicine_instances trg
  Set trg.medicine_price =
(select mi.medicine_price
  from   clientinfo 
         join orderinfo oi on oi.client_id = clientinfo.client_id
         join ordered_medicines om on om.order_id = oi.order_id
         join medicine_instances mi on om.medicine_id_instance = mi.medicine_id_instance
   where add_months(birthdate, 65*12) < CURRENT_DATE
     and mi.medicine_price in (select max(medicine_price) from medicine_instances)
     And mi.medicine_id_instance = trg.medicine_id_instance )
   Where exists
 (select 1
  from   clientinfo 
         join orderinfo oi on oi.client_id = clientinfo.client_id
         join ordered_medicines om on om.order_id = oi.order_id
         join medicine_instances mi on om.medicine_id_instance = mi.medicine_id_instance
   where add_months(birthdate, 65*12) < CURRENT_DATE
     and mi.medicine_price in (select max(medicine_price) from medicine_instances)
     And mi.medicine_id_instance = trg.medicine_id_instance )
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to put your query into a `MERGE` statement (correlating on the `ROWID` pseudo-column):

```sql
MERGE INTO medicine_instances dst
USING (
  select mi.ROWID AS rid
  from   clientinfo 
         join orderinfo oi
         on oi.client_id = clientinfo.client_id
         join ordered_medicines om
         on om.order_id = oi.order_id
         join medicine_instances mi
         on om.medicine_id_instance = mi.medicine_id_instance
  where  add_months(birthdate, 65*12) < CURRENT_DATE
  and    mi.medicine_price in (select max(medicine_price) from medicine_instances)
) src
ON ( src.rid = dst.ROWID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET medicine_price = src.medicine_price * 0.98;
```